# Trying to figure out the except statement in Python

Tags: python, except

I am having some trouble understanding ways to use the "except" statement in Python. I am a horrendous coder right now, so my apologies in advance.

Here is the small code I am trying to run:

```
def mathWorks():
    print " Answer the following: 5 + x = 10"

    x = int(raw_input("Please type your answer: "))

    if x == 5:
        print "You are correct!"
    else:
        print "You are incorrect!"
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "That is not an integer!"

mathWorks()
```

I think what I am trying to accomplish is pretty self explanatory. Unfortunately I am getting an "invalid syntax" for the "except" statement in this code.

What all am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need a `try:` before your `except:`

Comment: Is this exactly as it appears in your code? I ask because the body of the function is not indented at all, so for now your problem has nothing to do with except and everything to do with the lack of four spaces to indicate scope.

Comment: When posting questions on SO, please give the error in full. It makes it easier to help.

Answer (score 14):

`except` has to come after a `try` block. This signals the section of code that should have the exception handled:

```
try:
    x = int(raw_input("Please type your answer: "))
except ValueError:
    print "That is not an integer!"
```

Read it as 'try this, then do this if it fails'. Note it's good practice to do as little as possible in the `try` block - this ensures you don't catch errors you don't mean to (as does specifying the type of exception to catch, which you were already doing).

In this case, you might want to call `sys.exit(1)` in the `except` block as well, otherwise the program will continue (and fail with another error).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize a try: was always required before. Your explanation helps a bunch though. Thanks!

Comment: @user1901780 -- Feel free to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer (or any of the other answers) once your problem has been solved.  I'd choose this one though.  It's a pretty good one (as we've come to expect from Lattyware) :)

Answer (score 0):

It's used like this:

```
try: # try code here
except: # except errors here
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code, there is a "else" statement, you should use "else" statement after all of your except statements.

This is not directly related to your question, but you may encounter this further down.

Please refer to the original document for more details: 
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html